# Помогите заполнить форму c помощью requests post python

Tags: python, post, get, requests

Есть сайт :  https://servicesmmc.mos.ru/mmc-status/ndfl-payment-status.html
[image: форма сайте]

Нужно заполнить эту форму в скрипте.

Перечитал как заполнять формы, вроде делаю все верно однако, результат один тот же,та же страница, подскажите как правильно отправить запрос,причем капча постоянно меняется.

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import json

main_url = 'https://servicesmmc.mos.ru'
url = 'https://servicesmmc.mos.ru/mmc-status/ndfl-payment-status.html'
headers = {
    "user-agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}

url_post='https://servicesmmc.mos.ru/mmc-status/rest/ndfl-payment-status'

with req.Session() as session:
    resp = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(resp.headers)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
    captcha_url = main_url + bs.find_all(id='captchaImage')[0].get('src')
    with open('captcha.png', 'wb') as c:
        c.write(session.get(captcha_url).content)

    code_captcha = input('Введите код:')
    data = {'findByPassport': False,
            'captcha': code_captcha,
            "patentSerial": "12",
            "patentNumber": "3213333333",
            'falseissueDate': "03.08.2020",
            'createButton':'Проверить'}

    resp=session.post(url,headers=headers,data=data,)
    print(BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'html.parser').prettify())
    print(resp.headers)
```

То что видно в браузере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы передаёте обычную форму, а нужно передавать json, как видно на вашем скриншоте

Comment: @andreymal  resp=session.post(url,headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data)) не помогает

Comment: @andreymal не могли бы вы подсказать как правльно сделать запрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение на данный момент,рабочее: заменa url и headers

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import json

main_url = 'https://servicesmmc.mos.ru'
url = 'https://servicesmmc.mos.ru/mmc-status/ndfl-payment-status.html'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
     'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

url_post='https://servicesmmc.mos.ru/mmc-status/rest/ndfl-payment-status'

with req.Session() as session:
    resp = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(resp.headers)
    bs = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
    captcha_url = main_url + bs.find_all(id='captchaImage')[0].get('src')
    with open('captcha.png', 'wb') as c:
        c.write(session.get(captcha_url).content)

    code_captcha = input('Введите код:')
    data = {'findByPassport': False,
            'captcha': code_captcha,
            "patentSerial": "12",
            "patentNumber": "3213333333",
            'falseissueDate': "03.08.2020",
            'createButton':'Проверить'}

    resp=session.post(url_post,headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    print(BeautifulSoup(resp.text,'html.parser').prettify())
    print(resp.headers)
```

Ответ:
{"resultCode":"NOT_FOUND_PATENT_ERROR","status":null,"statusDetail":null,"requestFieldErrorList":null}